# async: true still requires associated Model in Ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I've got two Models using ember-data:

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
    'comments': DS.hasMany('comment', {async: true})
});

App.Comment = DS.Model.extend({
    postId: DS.belongsTo('post', {async: true})
});
```

When I try to get the Posts via a Route

```
model: function(params) {
    return this.store.find('post', params.query);
}
```

Ember tries to find the Comments, which are not Part of the Posts Response from the API, although "async" is set to true.

```
Cannot read property 'comments' of undefined
```

**Update**

Some more detailed informations, complementing the information above:

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create();
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    host: 'http://api.example.com'
});

App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    actions: {
        search: function() {
            var term = this.get('query');
            this.transitionToRoute('post', { query: term });
        },
        reset: function() {
            clearTimeout(this.get("timeout"));
            this.setProperties({
                isProcessing: false,
                isSlowConnection: false
            });
        }
    }
});

App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('post', { path:'/:query' }, function(){
        this.route('create');
        this.route('edit');
    });
});

App.PostRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        return this.store.find('post', params.query);
    }
});
```

**Data**

```
"posts": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Lorem ipsum",
        "comments": ["1", "2"],
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "dolor sit amet",
        "comments": ["1", "2"],
    }
]
```

And

```
"comments": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "body": "comment content 1",
        "postId": 1
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "body": "comment content 2",
        "postId": 1
    }
]
```

Comment: Are you trying to get comments that have already been stored on ember-data?

Comment: No, the comments aren't actually loaded, just the Posts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in a comment from ShinySides answer, Ember expects an object, instead of an array, because of the routing: if you got the route /posts the responded JSON has to be an Array with all posts:

```
"posts": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Lorem ipsum",
        "comments": ["1", "2"],
    },
]
```

But for the route /posts/search-for-whatever-in-posts Ember expects an object, representing just one post:

```
"post": {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Lorem ipsum",
    "comments": ["1", "2"],
},
```

The solution for my question: [QUERYING FOR RECORDS](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/finding-records/#toc_querying-for-records):

```
var posts = this.store.find('posts', { term: "search for whatever in posts" });
```

which adds a parameter "term" to the API request (e.g. api.example.com/posts?term=whatever). Ember will now return an array.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna get information that is already loaded on the store you need to use

```
this.store.all('post')
```

And then use filter to get the information you want as an example

```
this.store.all('post').filterBy('key', value)
```

have a look at the documentation for further information on filtering if you need 
http://emberjs.com/guides/enumerables/

Comment: The comments aren't already loaded, just the Posts, so I need to "find", to request the API

Comment: yes but if you do this.store.find('post') it's not gonna load comments, you need to do get .get('comments') on a post object for that.

Comment: Yes, but this should happen later on click: if you load the page, all Posts are visible and later, if a user clicks on a link, e.g. "show comments" by a specific Post, the Comments should load via Ajax.

Comment: Sorry now I understand what you mean, looking at the code it seems fine, do you have a view? or is there any other methods on the controller that is using comments? if you could post the full code it would be a lot easier to see the issue.

Comment: There is an empty View, just a scaffold without function. In my question above you can see the whole code.

Comment: As you can see, the API response returns two nested arrays. If "posts" isn't an array, but a single object, ember doesn't throw any errors and the data tab in ember console is filled with a post

Comment: I can see that, but I still don't understand why it's calling the comments, I have something very similar going right now in one of my projects and I just tested it to see if it would call the related fields, and it's not, that's why I'm wondering if any function on the controller is calling the comments, I wonder if the naming has anything to do with it, I don't think you need to call the post postId but just post, like this example http://emberjs.com/guides/models/defining-models/#toc_one-to-many

Comment: Which ember version do you use (I've tried 1.7.0 and 1.8.0 beta with ember-data 1.0 beta 11)? Do you have a working example, so I can compare it? Replacing the postid or even removing the relation from the comments model didn't work

Comment: Perhaps, depending on the route (s. http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html#toc_object-root) Ember expects an array or a single object: /posts/1 = object, /posts = array. But the dynamic parameter is not an id, it's a search term (e.g. /posts/ember-js which should display all results with "ember-js")